# iPhone App Button To Go To App Store and Leave a Review

Tags: iphone

I am trying to set up app where user can touch a button and go to the App Store to leave a review. I am using iPhone simulator 5.0 and I keep getting `the address is invalid`.

I am using this format:

```
-(IBAction) leaveReview {
    NSString *reviewURL = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mood-color-secrets-women/id495880078?ls=1&mt=8";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reviewURL]];
}
```

The address works in Safari as:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mood-color-secrets-women/id495880078?ls=1&mt=8

Do I have a format error? or Is something changed in iOS 5.0?

Is there an easy solution I am missing?

Comment: The simulator can't open an app that isn't installed on it!

Answer (score 4):

The `itms-apps://...` address is only works on devices.

BTW, try [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater), a utility that reminds your iPhone app's users to review the app.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this on a physical iOS device? If not, I think the issue may be that the iOS Simulator does not feature the AppStore. Therefore, since the URL Scheme says "itms-apps", the simulator is not finding the AppStore, so it will not open.

Answer (score 0):

For my Apps, I've used the following format (I put it in terms of your example.)

```
// Where 123456789 is the App ID
NSString *reviewURL = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=123456789";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reviewURL]];
```